# Express $x^6+x^2+1$ as a product of irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I know $p(x)=x^6+x^2+1$ doesn't have any roots in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ because $p(\bar{0})\neq 0$ and $p(\bar{1})\neq 0$. So it has to be either a product of a polynomial of degree $4$ and a polynomial of degree $2$ or two polynomials of degree $3$. I could try to solve
$$(x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)\cdot (x^2+ex+f)=x^6+x^2+1$$
But this would take me way too long if I had to do it in a test. Is there a quicker way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Freshman's dream to see that
$$
p(x)=(x^3 + x + 1)^2.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Since all powers are even, this is the square of a polynomial
$$x^6+x^2+1=(x^3+x+1)^2$$
note that $x^3+x+1$ has no roots: this means that it is irreducible. This concludes the factorization.

Comment: In $x^6+3x^4+x^2+3$ all the powers are even and it is not the square of a polynomial, I am not very sure of your statement

Comment: Isn't $x^6+3x^4+x^2+3=(x^3+3x^2+x+3)^2$? In characteristic $2$, of course....

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting at this if you didn't know already would be to say that if $$x^6+x^2+1=0$$ then $$x^6=x^2+1$$ and look for easy factorisations of each side. It is then easy to spot $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ and $x^6=\left(x^3\right)^2$ and you can deploy the difference of two squares.